# Bash - my script doesnt remember variables

Tags: bash, variables, ubuntu

My script doesn't work. It doesn't remember changed values of variables.
I made following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

kon_p=100
kon_m="nothing"

cat /etc/list | grep -v '#' | while read machine priority ;
do  
    if [ $priority -le $kon_p ]
    then
        kon_p=$priority 
        kon_m=$machine

    fi  

done

 echo priority machine is $kon_m with priority $kon_p
```

and the result is:

```
  priority machine is nothing with priority 100
```

why no changes?

file "list" is following

```
         Debian_pokus   1
         debian_2       2
         debian_3       3
```

anyone Can you help me please?

Comment: The variables are set in the subshell opened by the `while`, so the main process does not have access to them.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for a thorough explanation, including workarounds.

Comment: You deserve an award: http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [FAQ on this exact question on Greycat wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) (a bash reference).

## What's wrong

- your shebang is `bash` so use the [adequate test](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29): `[[ … ]]` or `(( … ))` ;
- you don't need the `cat`, [`grep` can't take a file as input](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) (*e.g.*: `grep <pattern> <file>`).
- your while loop is wrong, use a [redirect or process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024#Workarounds): `while …; do …; done < <(cmd)`

Read more about [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

## Solution

```
#!/bin/bash

kon_p=100
kon_m="nothing"

while read machine priority ; do  
    if (( $priority < $kon_p )); then
        kon_p=$priority 
        kon_m=$machine
    fi  
done < <(grep -v '#' /etc/list)

printf "priority machine is %s with priority %s\n" "$kon_m" $kon_p
```

Answer (score 0):

The subshell was doing you in, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

kon_p=100
kon_m="nothing"

IFS=$'\n'
for line in $(cat /etc/list | grep -v '#')
do  
    IFS=' ' read -ra values <<< "${line}"
    if [ ${values[1]} -le $kon_p ]
    then
        echo "doing it."
        kon_p=${values[1]} 
        kon_m=${values[0]}
    fi  
done

echo priority machine is $kon_m with priority $kon_p
```

Comment: don't do this can of loop [`for … in $()`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29), it behaves *inconsistently* depending on the source. Also read about [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting)

Comment: also see my response there is plenty of links to support it.

Comment: BTW, you can affect `kon_p` and `kon_m` directly in the `read`. Something like: `read -r kon_m kon_p leftover <<< "$line"`